# How to fix counter flashing

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a very simple game to try and ease into things, but ran into a problem pretty early on.

I have tried re-positioning where the timer is updated, but it just keeps flashing/flickering.

```py
def update_timer():
    global timer, timerrect
    # make timer text
    displaytext(f"{counter}", 50, 50)
    # dispay timer
    pygame.display.flip()
    return timer, timerrect

def displaytext(text, a, b):
    x = font.render(text, True, BLACK, WHITE)
    xrect = x.get_rect()
    xrect.center = (a, b)
    screen.blit(x, xrect)
    pygame.display.flip()

for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            counter-=1
            update_timer()

    # not-so-elegant displaying of timer
    try:
        screen.blit(timer, timerrect)
        pygame.display.flip()
    except:
        pygame.display.flip()

    # some more code here   

    # draw all sprites
    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    # fps
    clock.tick(60)


    # update screen
    pygame.display.flip()
```

As I said, the timer is constantly flickering. I'd like for it to not induce seizures /s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, when something is flickering in Pygame, there is one cause: You are calling `pygame.display.flip()` more than once per frame.

You should remove all calls to `pygame.display.flip()` except the one in your main loop (the one you have commented `# update screen`). This means that the display is updated only once per frame.

When there are additional `flip`s the screen updates on top of itself, and some frames may not end up with the timer visible.

Also, it looks like your `update_timer` function would work, if you remove the extra `flip`. Then you would not need the "not-so-elegant" code that you probably used to try debugging this problem.